# Disable form during NProgress

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I am new at [NProgress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/) and I have implement it in my project 
Add this script for NProgress

```
 <link href="~/Content/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="~/Scripts/nprogress.js"></script>

     // Increase randomly
    var interval = setInterval(function () { NProgress.inc(); }, 3000);

    ////// Trigger finish when page fully loaded
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
        NProgress.done();
    });

    ////// Trigger bar when exiting the page
    jQuery(window).unload(function () {
        NProgress.start();
    });

    $("[type=submit]").click(function () {            
        NProgress.start();
        //$("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        //$("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        //$("select").attr("disabled", "disabled");           
    });
```

I have to implement NProgress bar on save button and during save **I want to achieve functionality that One should not click or edit anything while saving** using NProgress bar

How can I implement with along NProgress bar

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve  want to achieve functionality that One should not click or edit 
   anything while saving using NProgress bar

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var interval = setInterval(function () { NProgress.inc(); }, 1);

$(this).ajaxSuccess(function () {
    $("button").css("pointer-events", "visible");
    $("input").removeAttr("readonly");
    $("select").removeAttr("readonly");
    clearInterval(interval);
    NProgress.done();
});


$(this).ajaxError(function () {
    MakeReadWrite();
    clearInterval(interval);
    NProgress.done();
});

// Trigger finish when page fully loaded
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
    NProgress.done();
});

// Trigger bar when exiting the page
jQuery(window).unload(function () {
    NProgress.start();
});

$("[type=submit]").click(function () {            
    $("button").css("pointer-events", "none");
    $("input").attr("readonly");
    $("select").attr("readonly");
    NProgress.start();        
});    

 });
```